# AdSupported Angry Birds versions keep crashing on Android 2.2.1 Tablet PC

Tags: angry-birds

After RTFM, I decided to ask the question here.

Device is a generic android tablet device (http://www.reeder.com.tr/reedpad.asp),

idenfied as: "sec_smdkv210"
here is the build fingerprint:
"sec_smdkv210/smdkv210/smdkv210:2.2.1/FRF91/eng.root.20110224.011402:eng/release"
Android Version: 2.2.1

Problem occurs after I launch Angry Birds Rio, and try to play the first level, at the very beginning, it just quits from the game.

System Log:

http://pastebin.com/aBmfvXtF

Game is an adsupported version 1.0.0 downloaded from market.

No ad blocker installed, no add-ons. Device is rooted by z4root, but before or after rooting, behaviour is same. Also, same crash behaviour is observed with Angry Birds Seasons, but slighly different, it crashes if you  try to pause and reload the level during the game, resulting a similiar crash log which I didn't bother to paste here once again.

Same string appears in the crash log before the crash:

**JNI WARNING: received null jstring (Check_GetStringUTFChars)**

W/dalvikvm(25888): JNI WARNING: received null jstring (Check_GetStringUTFChars)
I/dalvikvm(25888): "GLThread 9" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
I/dalvikvm(25888):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x46f97d70 self=0x225c10
I/dalvikvm(25888):   | sysTid=25895 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2251432
I/dalvikvm(25888):   | schedstat=( 7639180271 5104522289 130271 )
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.WebViewWrapper.urlLoadedCallback(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.WebViewWrapper.access$500(WebViewWrapper.java:42)
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.WebViewWrapper$8.run(WebViewWrapper.java:216)
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.MyRenderer.handleEvents(MyRenderer.java:118)
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.MyRenderer.onDrawFrame(MyRenderer.java:77)
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1346)
I/dalvikvm(25888):   at com.rovio.ka3d.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1121)

Trying to move from SD card to device did not help.
Trying to change the device locale from Turkish to English did not help.
Trying to update the device from manufacturer's site, did not help (it did not updated the android version, only manufacturer's build number changed)
Trying to root the device, did not help.

Anybody could suggest what could be going on here?

Best Regards,
q.m.

Comment: Whether anyone here can help you or not I highly suggest you submit this to the developer as well.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's basically a null pointer error when Angry birds tries to create a surface, which probably means that your device is simply incapable of doing the video rendering needed.  I don't believe Angry Birds Rio has a Light version, unlike the regular game, so you're probably out of luck unless they release a version for less-capable devices.

From http://www.rovio.com/index.php?page=angry-birds---frequently-asked-questions-faq:

> **Q: I have a problem with the Angry Birds. What should I do?**
>
> A: Check Rovio’s web-pages and browse this FAQ section for a solution. If you cannot find solutions for your problem or questions, please contact Rovio’s customer support by email and provide as much information about your problem as possible: phone/device model and/or version, phone/device operating system version, Angry Bird game’s name and its version, a detailed problem description.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to contact the game developer's support. I'll also update this post if any solution is found.